# Pip install argument from unix pipe

Tags: python, linux, pip, pipe

I intend to create a script able to install one single wheel file (.whl) at my enviroment using pip, but the file wheel file change the version very frequent. Ex: For now the file name is 
 Simulador-0.3.2.post0.dev2+g862e34a.dirty-py2.py3-none-any.whl
but soon will be ..-0.3.3- ....

For install this version I can try to do this
`pip install Simulador-0.3.2.post0.dev2+g862e34a.dirty-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

but this solution will stop to work as soon my version change, so I tried to create a ubuntu pipe

`ls *.whl | pip install`

But didn't work, show this message
"ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")" But don`t make sense, because the ls *.whl is sending a argument.

Any suggestion to fix the pipe?

Comment: Chepner's answer is the canonical way of dealing with this. The accepted answer lists the error prone parsing of `ls` as the preferred method (and should be purged with fire ;})...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like

```
pip install `ls *.whl`
```

Where subcommand

```
`ls *.whl`
```

generates files list and echoes it as strings which is used by `pip` for install

Or without passing any arguments from other command result like discussed

```
pip install *.whl
```

Comment: you may want to explain the ` ... ` (subshell piece)

Comment: `pip install *.whl` be far preferable.

Comment: this way as wel :) just wanted to show how to pass other command result

Comment: Don't, because that's not guaranteed to work. The command substitution is subject to word splitting and pathname expansion, so there's no guarantee that `pip` sees the file names you do. It's the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @RodrigoPG *Do not* use `ls` like this.

Answer (score 2):

The pipe connects the standard output of `ls` to the standard input of `pip`, but `pip` doesn't read its standard input for packages to install. It looks at its arguments, of which there are none.

Use

```
pip install *.whl
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` to the rescue!

`ls *.whl | xargs pip install`