# Combine Curl and Pip Install

Tags: python, ubuntu, curl, pip, pipe

If my `requirements.txt` file is hosted on a remote server, is it possible to combine `curl` with `pip` so that we can download the `requirements.txt` file and pipe it into `pip install -r` without having to save the file to disk?

Tried this

```
curl http://my-requirements.txt.example.com | pip install -r
```

but got the error

```
-r option requires 1 argument
```

Comment: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59396731/11658924) answer, you can `pip install \`curl my-requirements.txt.example.com\``

Comment: `curl http://my-requirements.txt.example.com -o requirements.txt && pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: With [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html): `pip install -r <(curl http://my-requirements.txt.example.com)`